# Disproportionate sizes between letters and numbers in math-mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize, scaling

Is it just me that thinks that numbers in math-mode are disproportionately sized in comparison to letters? I am using the font Tex Gyre Termes. It is particularly noticeable in subscripts. For example:

```
$A_{rs}, A_{1s}, A_{r2}$
```

which gives

[image]

Is there anyone else that is slightly vexed by this? If so, is there a solution to normalise the size between numbers and letters?

Comment: Numbers are bigger than lowercase letters. I see no “disproportion”.

Comment: @egreg If you look at the proportions of the letters and numbers in the code section of my post, they're clearly different to the associated latex font. This clearly suggests that different fonts have different proportions between letters and numbers.  For whatever reason, Tex Gyre Termes seems to pronounce the difference in sizes a lot more.

Comment: @egreg My issue is not so much that "numbers are bigger than lowercase letters", but the degree by which they are bigger than them. The latter seems to be variable in different fonts.

Comment: Numbers have the height of capital letters and no depth. You may want to use old-style figure, which have the height of lowercase letters, and some may have a non-zero depth.

Comment: @Bernard Okay, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Choose a font with a large x-height (larger lowercase letters). Bitstream Vera is one free possibility.